# Blend transparent gradient with an image using php GD library

Tags: php, image, gd, gradient

I try to render gradient on top of an image it need to be from full color to transparent, here is my code. I get black image and if I put start more then 0 I got white gradient but no image. the output image is 338x100 px but the input image need to be aligned to right if the image is narrower.

```
function hex2rgb($hex) {
    $rgb[0] = hexdec(substr($hex, 0, 2));
    $rgb[1] = hexdec(substr($hex, 2, 2));
    $rgb[2] = hexdec(substr($hex, 4, 2));
    return $rgb;
}

function int2rgb($color) {
    $result[] = ($color >> 16) & 0xFF;
    $result[] = ($color >> 8) & 0xFF;
    $result[] = $color & 0xFF;
    return $result;
}

if (isset($_GET['start']) && isset($_GET['stop']) && isset($_GET['color'])) {
    $input = imagecreatefrompng('file.png');
    $width = imagesx($input);
    $output = imagecreatetruecolor(338, 100);
    $color = hex2rgb($_GET['color']);
    $fill = imagecolorallocate($output, $color[0], $color[1], $color[2]);


    for ($x=0; $x<$_GET['start']; ++$x) {
        for ($y=0; $y<100; ++$y) {
            imagesetpixel($output, $x, $y, $fill);
        }
    }
    $range = $_GET['stop']-$_GET['start'];
    for ($x=$_GET['start']; $x<$_GET['stop']; ++$x) {
        $alpha = round(255-($x*255/$range));
        $correct_x = $width < 338 ? $x+$width-338 : $x;
        for ($y=0; $y<100; ++$y) {
            $input_color = int2rgb(imagecolorat($input, $correct_x, $y));

            $new_color = imagecolorallocate($output,
                                            (($color[0]-$alpha)*$input_color[0])/255,
                                            (($color[1]-$alpha)*$input_color[1])/255,
                                            (($color[2]-$alpha)*$input_color[2])/255);
            imagesetpixel($output, $x, $y, $new_color);
        }
    }
    if ($_GET['stop']<338) {
        $stop = $width < 338 ? $_GET['stop']+$width-338 : $_GET['stop'];
        imagecopy($input, $output, $stop, 0, $_GET['stop'], 0, 338-$stop, 100);
        header('Content-Type: image/png');
        imagepng($output);
    }
}
```

I run the script with `gradient.php?start=20&stop=200&color=ff0000` and got this instead of red gradient.

[image]
[image]

How to make that gradient red from full color to full transparent? So it look like this:

[image]

Comment: Does it have to be with `GD` ?

Comment: @Baba no, if it will work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you create a image using [imagecreatetruecolor](http://php.net/imagecreatetruecolor) it gets a black background. Using [imagefill](http://php.net/imagefill) you can change the background of an image easily.  The [imagecolorallocatealpha](http://php.net/imagecolorallocatealpha) function let's you create a color containing transparency. 127 means fully transparent and 0 not transparent.

It works now and I simplified your code a bit:

```
function hex2rgb($hex) {
    $rgb[0] = hexdec(substr($hex, 0, 2));
    $rgb[1] = hexdec(substr($hex, 2, 2));
    $rgb[2] = hexdec(substr($hex, 4, 2));
    return $rgb;
}

if (isset($_GET['start']) && isset($_GET['stop']) && isset($_GET['color'])) {
    $color = hex2rgb($_GET['color']);
    $range = $_GET['stop']-$_GET['start'];

    // create input image
    $input = imagecreatefrompng('file.png');


    // create output image
    $height = imagesy($input);
    $width = imagesx($input);
    $output = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

    // put a transparent background on it
    $trans_colour = imagecolorallocatealpha($output, 0, 0, 0, 127);
    imagefill($output, 0, 0, $trans_colour);

    // create the gradient
    for ($x=0; $x < $width; ++$x) {
        $alpha = $x <= $_GET['start'] ? 0 : round(min(($x - $_GET['start'])/$range, 1)*127);
        $new_color = imagecolorallocatealpha($output, $color[0], $color[1], $color[2], $alpha);
        imageline($output, $x, $height, $x, 0, $new_color);
    }

    // copy the gradient onto the input image
    imagecopyresampled($input, $output, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height);

    // output the result
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($input);
}
```

Comment: Superb. It took me al while to figure out how to use this for an alpha transparency on the other (right) side of the image:
`$alpha = $x <= $start ? 127 : round(min(($stop-$x)/$range, 1)*127;`
where $stop is equal to the width of the image.

Comment: I understand this problem is several years old at this point, although what is the best way of translating this to begin at the bottom of an image with gradient finishing in the photo rather than at the bottom?